# Read byte fails on Raspberry Pi 3: [errno 5] input/output error

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi3, meta-raspberrypi

I have adafruit pressure and temperature sensor BMP180 connected to I2C of Raspberry Pi 3. The device is detected on 0x77 address of I2C, i2cdump runs with no error and shows correct values (e.g. byte 0x55 in 0xD0 as described in Bosch documentation). But reading a byte in most cases results in input/output error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 29 -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 77                     

pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_BMP $ i2cdump -y 1 0x77
No size specified (using byte-data access)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
10: XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    XXX.............
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
80: a5 94 46 29 82 27 75 20 c8 0b 22 91 fb 57 c7 11    ??F)?'u ??"??W??
90: 85 ca 61 f6 45 8a 19 73 00 30 80 00 d1 f6 0a d4    ??a?E??s.0?.????
a0: a5 94 46 29 82 27 75 20 c8 0b 22 91 fb 57 c7 11    ??F)?'u ??"??W??
b0: 85 ca 61 f6 45 8a 19 73 00 30 80 00 d1 f6 0a d4    ??a?E??s.0?.????
c0: 00 00 bc 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 03    ..?3.......?...?
d0: 55 02 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    U??.............
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ......?.........

pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_BMP $ i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0
0x55
pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_BMP $ i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0
Error: Read failed
pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_BMP $ i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0
Error: Read failed
```

Executing example from Adafruit (for BMP180 sensor) in most cases also returns error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_BMP $ python test.py 
Temp = 23.40 *C
Pressure = 99105.00 Pa
pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_BMP $ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_BMP/Adafruit_BMP/BMP085.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._load_calibration()
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_BMP/Adafruit_BMP/BMP085.py", line 72, in _load_calibration
    self.cal_AC1 = self._device.readS16BE(BMP085_CAL_AC1)   # INT16
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 200, in readS16BE
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 177, in readS16
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 164, in readU16
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 173, in read_word_data
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I have also written scripts to read bytes from this sensor, using either smbus2 or smbus-cffi. The result is the same: rarely bytes are read, in most cases I get errors:

```
➜  birdwatcher git:(master) ✗ cat bmp180.py | ssh pi@192.168.1.11 sudo python -
2016-12-30 19:30:40,608 __main__                       DEBUG    AC1 = -29482 [-0x732a]
2016-12-30 19:30:40,609 __main__                       DEBUG    AC2 = 22523 [0x57fb]
2016-12-30 19:30:40,609 __main__                       DEBUG    AC3 = 4551 [0x11c7]
2016-12-30 19:30:40,610 __main__                       DEBUG    AC4 = 51845 [0xca85]
2016-12-30 19:30:40,610 __main__                       DEBUG    AC5 = 63073 [0xf661]
2016-12-30 19:30:40,610 __main__                       DEBUG    AC6 = 35397 [0x8a45]
➜  birdwatcher git:(master) ✗ cat bmp180.py | ssh pi@192.168.1.11 sudo python -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 101, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 68, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 49, in read_uint8
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Here is some information about environment:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -a /dev/i2c*
/dev/i2c-1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /boot/config.txt | grep i2c
dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=100000
dtoverlay=i2c-sensor
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   10340  2 
hci_uart               17943  1 
btbcm                   5929  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             326105  22 bnep,btbcm,hci_uart
brcmfmac              186403  0 
brcmutil                5661  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              428431  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 16037  4 cfg80211,bluetooth
snd_bcm2835            20447  0 
snd_pcm                75762  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              19288  1 snd_pcm
snd                    51908  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
bcm2835_wdt             3225  0 
bcm2835_gpiomem         3040  0 
uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0 
uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_bcm2708             4834  0 
i2c_dev                 5859  0 
fuse                   84037  1 
ipv6                  347594  30
```

**Summary:** 
i2cdump reads all bytes from sensor, but reading via i2cget fails in most cases. The behaviour is random and inconsistent (in most cases it results in error).

I have also collected data about signals on wires using piscope.
Here is a successful i2cget:
[i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0 - returns 0x55](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiBp4.png)

And here is a failed byte read:
[i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0 - Error: Read failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW89w.png)

Comment: check the hardware connection

Comment: @eyllanesc the hardware connection is stable as if I run i2cdump I always get correct data (no errors after i2cdump, i2cdetect always shows sensor present).

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38815505/1699210)

Comment: I have also collected data about signals on wires using piscope.
Here is a successful i2cget:
[i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0 - returns 0x55](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiBp4.png)

And here is a failed byte read:
[i2cget -y 1 0x77 0xd0 - Error: Read failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW89w.png)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
I had wrong connection on GND bus.